# Cells flash up when data entered in referenced cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a number of sheets. Data is entered into Sheet A, then other sheets (Sheet B in this example) reference this data, and use a variety of conditional statements and conditional formatting rules to display this data.

When I enter data into cell A in Sheet A, a number of cells from Sheet B briefly pop up. All the cells that pop up are part of a conditional formatting rule.

I noticed the problem goes away when I manually hide and unhide the offending sheets. When I try doing this via a macro it does not fix the problem.

```
Sub FixNodeIssues()
Sheets("Switch Labels").Visible = False
Sheets("Node Labels").Visible = False

Sheets("Switch Labels").Visible = True
Sheets("Node Labels").Visible = True
End Sub
```

I've had a hunt through Excel's settings and can't see anything obvious which may be causing this.

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` as the first line.  Then `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` as the last line.

Comment: Do the formulae on Sheet B use user defined functions?  If so do any of these UDFs use Select or Activate?

Comment: None of the formulae in Sheet B user UDFs.